# Why does \mathchoice mess with my redefined superscript?

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I redefined `^` to give different colors depending on whether it is a superscript, supersuperscript, etc using the following:

```
\catcode`^\active
\def^#1{%
    \mathchoice{%
        \sp{\color{red}#1}%
    }{%
        \sp{\color{blue}#1}%
    }{
        \sp{\color{green}#1}%
    }{
        \sp{\color{orange}#1}%
    }%
}
```

This yields
[image]

which is what I wanted. However, when I have a big operator like `\sum`, the code

```
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}
```

yields
[image]
instead of putting the `\infty` correctly in the limit. If I don't use `\mathchoice`, this doesn't happen. Is there a way to fix this?

Side note: I'm not sure why blue is skipped in the colors. Shouldn't the `k` and `+1` be blue, not green?

Comment: even with `x^2` you are not putting the superscript on x but on an empty atom like `x{^2}` it is just more obvious with `\sum`

Comment: you have not shown any source for your example so hard to answer your side note but presumably you started in displaystyle then have superscripts so textstyle not used. If you had started in textstyle red would not be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following avoids the use of `\mathchoice`, and has been edited using input from @egreg, @David Carlisle and @wipet.

First note that changing catcodes is inherently risky. Whilst it's possible to achieve the result you want, there are situations in which 'standard' catcodes are expected by other code such as packages. One of these occurs when `mathtools` is loaded: an error will occur if `^` is catcoded to active. @egreg's answer avoids this by locally setting the catcode inside a group, and then globally switching it at the beginning of the document; I have borrowed this here. However, there may be other nasty surprises.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcount\sup
\sup=0
\bgroup
\catcode`\^=13
\gdef^#1{\sp{\advance\sup by1 {\color{\ifcase\sup\or red\or blue\or green\else orange\fi}#1}}}
\egroup
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`^=\active}
%
\begin{document}
\[ x^{1/4^{k^\alpha}+1} \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\]
\end{document}
```

The counter advances by 1 each time you move up a script level, and decreases again when you drop down, because the increase happens inside a group. Here I must credit @wipet, who suggested this very concise implementation.

[image]

Comment: Good idea. You can do your code more compact: `\def^#1{\sp{\advance\sup by1 {\color{\ifcase\sup\or red\or blue\or green\else orange\fi}#1}}`

Comment: I actually like this a lot more than using `\mathchoice`.

Comment: @wipet --- Very neat. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you misunderstood what the arguments to `\mathchoice` are used for.

The reason you don't get blue is that you probably had the formula in `\displaystyle`.

When you say

```
\mathchoice{a}{b}{c}{d}
```

TeX will use `a` in display style, `b` in text style, `c` in script style and finally `d` in scriptscript style (second or further level of subscripts or superscripts). They're not what's used at base, first, second or third level as one can guess from your post: TeX treats third level super/subscript just like second level ones.

Plain TeX example (it's the same in LaTeX):

```
$$
\mathchoice{a}{b}{c}{d}
+
{\mathchoice{a}{b}{c}{d}\over2}
+x^{\mathchoice{a}{b}{c}{d}}
+x^{y^{\mathchoice{a}{b}{c}{d}}}
$$
\bye
```

[image]

The first `\mathchoice` results in *a* because TeX is in display style; the second one yields *b* because the numerator of a fraction found in display style is processed in text style. The other two cases should be clear.

Now let's try

```
$$
A\mathchoice{\sp{a}}{\sp{b}}{\sp{c}}{\sp{d}}
+
{A\mathchoice{\sp{a}}{\sp{b}}{\sp{c}}{\sp{d}}\over2}
$$
```

The first `\mathchoice` is in display style and the second one is in text style and we get

[image]

which is probably not what you expected, but it could be predicted when knowing the exact rule.

Now let's try

```
$$
\left( 1\over 2 \right)\mathchoice{\sp{a}}{\sp{b}}{\sp{c}}{\sp{d}}
$$
```

[image]

Oops! The `\mathchoice` is processed in its own math list and the subscript is *not* to the previous atom that received no superscript field.

With LuaTeX you can do better, but with TeX the best you can get is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begingroup
\catcode`^=\active
\protected\gdef^#1{%
  \sp{\mathchoice{}{}%
        {\mathcolor{green!80!blue}{#1}}%
        {\mathcolor{orange}{#1}}%
  }%
}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`^=\active}

\begin{document}

\[
x^{a^{b^{c}}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a^{k}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can do better with LuaTeX where you can always query the current `\mathstyle` (an integer from 0 to 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begingroup
\catcode`^=\active
\protected\gdef^#1{%
  \ifcase\mathstyle
    \sp{\mathcolor{blue!80!green}{#1}}% 0 = D
  \or
    \sp{\mathcolor{blue!80!green}{#1}}% 1 = D'
  \or
    \sp{\mathcolor{blue!80!green}{#1}}% 2 = T
  \or
    \sp{\mathcolor{blue!80!green}{#1}}% 3 = T'
  \or
    \sp{\mathcolor{green!80!blue}{#1}}% 4 = S
  \or
    \sp{\mathcolor{green!80!blue}{#1}}% 5 = S'
  \or
    \sp{\mathcolor{orange}{#1}}% 6 = SS
  \or
    \sp{\mathcolor{orange}{#1}}% 7 = SS'
  \fi
}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`^=\active}

\begin{document}

\[
x^{a^{b^{c}}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a^{k}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed that catcoding `^` to active causes trouble with `\begin{document}` (hence the grouping and use of `\AtBeginDocument`) . Is there any danger it could cause trouble elsewhere?

Comment: @IanThompson Changing catcodes is always a bit risky.

Comment: I wonder if we should look at adding `\mathstyle` to the other engines? Should be easy enough

Comment: @JosephWright That could be a very good idea! But also `\Ustack`, of course.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

even with `x^2` you are not putting the superscript on x but on an empty atom like `x{^2}` it is just more obvious with `\sum`

Move `\sp` outside

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

{\catcode`^\active
\gdef^#1{\sp{\mathchoice
    {\mathcolor{red}{#1}}%
    {\mathcolor{blue}{#1}}%
    {\mathcolor{green}{#1}}%
    {\mathcolor{orange}{#1}}%
    }%
}
}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`^\active}
\begin{document}

\[
x^{{1/4}^{k^\alpha}+1}
+
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: red and blue will never be used

Comment: Is there a way to do it with `\sp` inside `\mathchoice`? Just curious

Comment: @btshepard no, not with `^` syntax, you'd need to pull the  base into the mathchoice as well.

Comment: @btshepard a more robust way would not use mathchoice at all but use coloured fonts

Comment: On my machine (installation two years old), catcoding `^` to active caused `\begin{document}` to break. Don't you need a trick like @egreg used, with grouping and `\AtBeginDocument', or has something changed to allow your code to run?

Comment: Also (the same question I asked @egreg), is there any danger that catcoding `^` to active could cause trouble elsewhere?

Comment: @IanThompson oh sure it would break lots of things: `x^\frac12`  or `x^\mathrm{a}` or `^^41` but the code posted here runs in tl2022

Comment: Does it run if you load `mathtools`?

Comment: @IanThompson no the `^^` syntax (that I mentioned above) is used (so breaks) That's "expected outcome" but perhaps only if you have the right expectation. I adjusted.

Comment: Thanks; now I understand what's going on!